# Script output after timeout command

Tags: php, bash, timeout, symfony-1.4, output

i use symfony (php framework) task class to create cli scripts. Currently i wrote this kind of script:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 3600 ./symfony pparse:prices
```

But there is no output, I need that script will exit after 3600 sec. and ./symfony pparse:prices output data to console. Timeout is working, but no output.

Comment: Please show us the code of the execute() function of your task

Comment: @Herode php script works fine without timeout command before it

Comment: @Herode i use linux timout command instead of set_time_limit because timout works for me, but php function is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why, but currently it work fine. Maybe this is issue to OS.