# Capture output of a timed out command using Ubuntu `timeout`

Tags: bash, timeout, sh

Related questions:

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582048/script-output-after-timeout-command) ended up not requiring a resolution.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382626/timeout-a-command-efficiently-and-capture-output-to-a-variable-in-bash-script) had a resolution not involving `timeout`, but suggested that `timeout` should work for this purpose when available.

My question:

This command produces no output into `foo.txt`:

```
$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/sh
sh -c "echo foo; sleep 5; echo bar" | awk '/foo/ {print $1}'
$ timeout 2 ./foo.sh > foo.txt
```

If I don't redirect into `foo.txt`, I see `foo` print out immediately as expected.

On the other hand, the following produces "foo" int the file `foo.txt` as expected:

```
$ timeout 2 sh -c "echo foo; sleep 5; echo bar" > foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt
foo
```

Does anyone know why this may be happening and how best to resolve it? This is a toy example, but the actual script I'm running that led to this problem produces around 100 lines of output on the command line, but also leaves `foo.txt` empty if it times out before terminating.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is because pipe "|" wait "echo foo; sleep 5; echo bar" run complete .So after 5s awk can get the output, but timeout terminate the command in 2s so it cannot get the text.

Edit:

Maybe this helps, you can move char (") to the end like this:

```
$ cat foo.sh 
#!/bin/sh
sh -c "echo foo; sleep 5; echo bar | awk '/foo/ {print $1;}'"
$ timeout 2 ./foo.sh > foo.txt
$ cat foo.txt 
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this. The key is to add `fflush()` inside the awk script, which seemed to be buffering the output:

```
#!/bin/sh
sh -c "echo foo; sleep 5; echo bar" | awk '/foo/ {print $1; fflush()}'
$ timeout 2 ./foo.sh > foo.txt
```